# Missing heartbeat of client machine

Tags: c++, linux

My application launches hundreds of child processes sent to SGE. Few of them take a lot of memory due to which jobs are being failed.
i need some way to monitor the memory usage of clients from main process and relaunch/resubmit them to grid with higher memory requirement in case of such job failures.
i have heard something about missing heartbeat algo for such requirements but I am not much aware of them.
Can experts here please help me in finding out a nice solution for this issue? my application is a c++ application on Linux/Solaris.

Thanks
Ruchi

Answer (score 0):

A solution I have used before is to have a script that captures the output from the [qstat](http://gridscheduler.sourceforge.net/htmlman/htmlman1/qstat.html)-command (using rsh in my case). I filter on my jobs and store the information I need (in my case it was CPU) in a continuously updated list. When a job aborted or was killed, it was easy to go back and look at the CPU usage. It is not 100% real-time, but good enough for me.

My language of choice was Python, as it contains easy-to-use libraries for catching output and logging in to remote machines. However, it should be easy to implement something like capturing rsh-output in C++. You can for example use [popen()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen) to pipe the output into your application. I hope this helps.